# Calling a REST endpoint parallelly but the calls within a given period must be limited

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I have the following use case: calling a REST endpoint periodically with different params parallelly BUT the calls within a given period must be limited because the REST endpoint only serves a certain number of requests per period. Okay, the REST endpoint drops the requests from the same user or IP within the given period, so REST handles the issue but we do not want to overload the REST endpoint with useless requests.

This use case is simple, and it seems that not crazy hard to implement it. My solution works fine but sometimes behaves in a strange way (and I think it contains too much code). Is there any easiest, zero codings Spring conform way to implement this scenario?

My solution is based on a token-based pattern: There is a bucket, contains tokens. Before a task starts running take a token from the bucket. Then when the task finished it releasing the token. The another scheduled, parallel tasks must wait if no more free token in the basket.

**Token:**

```
public class Token {
    private String id;
    private Long startAt;
    private Long finishedAt;
}
```

**TokenBucket:**

```
public class TokenBucket {

    private static Vector<Token> tokens;
    private static long lengthOfPeriod;
    private static long maxRequestsWithinPeriod;

    // initialize
    public TokenBucket(long lengthOfPeriod, long maxRequestsWithinPeriod) {
        this.lengthOfPeriod = lengthOfPeriod;
        this.maxRequestsWithinPeriod = maxRequestsWithinPeriod;
        tokens = new Vector<>();
    }

    // occupy a token for the new running task
    public synchronized boolean get(String id) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long runningTasks = tokens.stream().filter(token -> token.getFinishedAt() == null).count();
        long completedWithinPeriod = tokens.stream()
                .filter(token -> Objects.nonNull(token.getFinishedAt()) && (token.getFinishedAt() >= now - lengthOfPeriod))
                .count();

        boolean hasToken = false;

        System.out.println(String.format("running: %d, completed: %d, tokens: %s", runningTasks, completedWithinPeriod, tokens.toString()));
        if (runningTasks + completedWithinPeriod < maxRequestsWithinPeriod ) {
            tokens.add(Token.builder().id(id).startAt(now).build());
            hasToken = true;
        }
        return hasToken;
    }

    // release token when a taskfinished
    public synchronized void release(String id) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        tokens.stream().filter(t -> t.getId() == id).findFirst().get().setFinishedAt(now);
        maintaining();
    }

    // delete old, useless tokens 
    private void maintaining() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Iterator<Token> iterator = tokens.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Token token = iterator.next();
            if (Objects.nonNull(token.getFinishedAt()) && now - token.getFinishedAt() > lengthOfPeriod) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Task:**

```
public class Task implements Runnable {

    private String id;
    TokenBucket tokenBucket;

    // inject the bucket spring bean
    public Task(String id, TokenBucket tokenBucket) {
        this.id = id;
        this.tokenBucket = tokenBucket;
    }

    // this code does the job
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (tokenBucket.get(id)) {
            // simulating the rest call
            long delay = (long) (Math.random() * 10000);
            System.out.println(String.format("%s task %s is running..., delay: %d", getTimestamp(), id, delay));
            delay(delay);
            System.out.println(String.format("%s task %s has been finished", timestampAsString(), id));
            tokenBucket.release(id);
        } else {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s task %s is skipped", timestampAsString(), id));
        }
    }

    // only for testing purpose
    private void delay(long delayInMilliseconds) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**spring configuration:**

```
@Configuration
public class TaskSchedulerConfiguration {

    private static final int MAX_REQUESTS_WITHIN_PERIOD = 2;
    private static final long LENGTH_OF_PERIOD = 1000;

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(MAX_REQUESTS_WITHIN_PERIOD);
        return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenBucket tokenBucket() {
        return new TokenBucket(LENGTH_OF_PERIOD, MAX_REQUESTS_WITHIN_PERIOD);
    }
}
```

**and finally my main task scheduler:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;
    TokenBucket tokenBucket;

    public Application(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler, TokenBucket tokenBucket) {
        this.taskScheduler = taskScheduler;
        this.tokenBucket = tokenBucket;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Task("1", tokenBucket), 5000);
        taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Task("2", tokenBucket), 5000);
        taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Task("3", tokenBucket), 5000);
        taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Task("4", tokenBucket), 5000);
    }
}
```

As I mentioned before this code runs fine, but the calling of the methods a little bit strange despite the `synchronized` keywords:

```
running: 0, completed: 0, tokens: []
16:27:01:147 task 1 is running..., delay: 3576
running: 1, completed: 0, tokens: [Token(id=1, startAt=1598970421145, finishedAt=null)]
16:27:01:152 task 2 is running..., delay: 5586
16:27:04:723 task 1 has been finished
running: 1, completed: 1, tokens: [Token(id=1, startAt=1598970421145, finishedAt=1598970424723), Token(id=2, startAt=1598970421147, finishedAt=null)]
16:27:04:724 task 3 is skipped
running: 1, completed: 1, tokens: [Token(id=1, startAt=1598970421145, finishedAt=1598970424723), Token(id=2, startAt=1598970421147, finishedAt=null)]
16:27:04:724 task 4 is skipped
16:27:06:738 task 2 has been finished
running: 0, completed: 0, tokens: [Token(id=2, startAt=1598970421147, finishedAt=1598970426738)]
16:27:09:724 task 1 is running..., delay: 763
running: 1, completed: 0, tokens: [Token(id=2, startAt=1598970421147, finishedAt=1598970426738), Token(id=1, startAt=1598970429724, finishedAt=null)]
16:27:09:724 task 3 is running..., delay: 498
16:27:10:222 task 3 has been finished
running: 1, completed: 1, tokens: [Token(id=1, startAt=1598970429724, finishedAt=null), Token(id=3, startAt=1598970429724, finishedAt=1598970430222)]
16:27:10:222 task 4 is skipped
16:27:10:487 task 1 has been finished
running: 0, completed: 0, tokens: [Token(id=1, startAt=1598970429724, finishedAt=1598970430487), Token(id=3, startAt=1598970429724, finishedAt=1598970430222)]
16:27:11:739 task 2 is running..., delay: 7804
running: 1, completed: 0, tokens: [Token(id=1, startAt=1598970429724, finishedAt=1598970430487), Token(id=3, startAt=1598970429724, finishedAt=1598970430222), Token(id=2, startAt=1598970431738, finishedAt=null)]
16:27:15:223 task 3 is running..., delay: 7761
```

Why sometimes the `TokenBucket.get()` method is called earlier than the new task just finished (`TokenBucket.release`)?

This is strange and it was hard to manage this situation.

Is there any Java framework or Spring "codless" solution for this use case?

Comment: Have you checked the Spring WebFlux framework:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html
I think you may find this useful?

Comment: Just in case, the mechanism you are looking for is called "Throttling", maybe you can find easier a spring solution searching for that term.